# GetCheck() working for check buttons but not radio buttons?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm just learning about making dialog boxes with MFC in Visual Studio 2010.

From what I can see [on msdn's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the GetCheck() function should work the same for both check boxes and radio buttons.

Basically I have two radio buttons next to two sliders.  If one radio button is on, that slider is disabled, and if the other radio button is on, then the other slider is disabled.

When I had the radio buttons switched out for check boxes, this was the code i used:

```
void Cstring_copyierDlg::OnBnClickedSld1chk()
{

    UINT nCheck = m_slide1check.GetCheck();

    if(nCheck == BST_CHECKED){
        m_slider.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
    else{
        m_slider.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
```

}

```
void Cstring_copyierDlg::OnBnClickedSld2chk()
{
    UINT nCheck = m_slide2check.GetCheck();

    if(nCheck == BST_CHECKED){
        m_slider2.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
    else{
        m_slider2.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
```

}

This code worked fine. But when I switched out the check boxes for radio buttons, this is the code i used:

```
void Cstring_copyierDlg::OnBnClickedRad1()
{

    UINT nCheck = m_radio1.GetCheck();

    if(nCheck == BST_CHECKED){
        m_slider.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
    else{
        m_slider.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
```

}

```
void Cstring_copyierDlg::OnBnClickedRad2()
{
    UINT nCheck = m_radio2.GetCheck();

    if(nCheck == BST_CHECKED){
        m_slider2.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
    else{
        m_slider2.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
```

}

However the second piece of code returns the following error upon compilation:

```
error C2228: left of '.GetCheck' must have class/struct/union
```

What gives?

Comment: What type is `m_radio1`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what type it is, but to create m_radio1 i Ctrl+double clicked the radio button and set "Variable Name:" as m_radio1.  Idk what type that makes it by default though.

Comment: Visual Studio brought back the MFC Class Wizard. If you press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+X it pops up a dialog with all the information you need. Select the Dialog/View class from the _Class name_ combo box and click the _Member Variables_ tab. This should help you identify the type of `m_radio1`. Unrelated to your question, I wouldn't recommend starting Windows development using MFC. Wading through the auto generated code isn't going to provide the insight you need. In essence if you start with MFC you're skipping a mandatory learning experience: Plain vanilla Win32 API programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing the wrong variable type for the DDX in the add variable wizard. You should choose the control type there.

To change the variable type manually, replace the type of the m_radio1 to CButton and replace  DDX_Radio with DDX_Control in DoDataExchange.